# Bash ping server with addres and port and get short info

Tags: bash, networking, ip, port, netcat

How I can connect to sever by ip and port, and get short info about it? 
I tried to do it with `netcat` and `curl`, but info is too long. I also tried to use telnet but it is not a good way for me.
I have a script which connect to some addresses on specified ports and I if it is connected I want to show short info about it. 
Is it possible? Is any other method to solve this problem?

IP addresses are different. They can be a http, mysql, ssl, etc.

I attach a code with a connection's function:

```
if nc -w 10 -z $1 $i; then  
        printf "\n$1:$i - Port is open\n\nSERVER INFO:\n";  
        printf "\n$(curl -IL $1)\n";        
    else
        printf "\n$1:$i - Port is closed\n"
fi;
```

**EDIT:**
Example of response from server I would like to get

```
{IP number}: ssh - OpenSSH 6.0pl1, http - apache 1.3.67, https - httpd 2.0.57
```

Comment: What kind of info are you trying to get?  Have you considered using `nmap`?

Comment: I cannot use nmap (this is task for my studies). I need something similar to nmap. I need only basic about server. It has to be only in one line or short like this. Maybe I can get this info from curl, but in shorter way?

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to get?  Do you want to just map the port to the likely application?  Do you want to try to get OS information about the remote system?  Do you want to get application version information?  Do you want to estimate the uptime of the remote system?  There's lots of types of information you might want, and it'll be hard to help without some more detail about what you want.  Could you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40160191/edit) to include an example of the output you would like.

Comment: I edited. Application version, OS info and info from example in the post should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. You can include the host just as you have in your script.

```
for port in $(seq 21 23); do
   out=$(nc -w 1 -q 1 localhost $port)
   echo port ${port}: $out
done

#port 21:
#port 22: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
#port 23:
```

Comment: I don't see -q in nc specification http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/nc.htm

Comment: I'm running ubuntu and it is in the manual.

Try `man nc` on your terminal

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/nc_openbsd.1.html

Comment: I'm using win 10 and cygwin.

Comment: I try out=$(nc -w 10 $1 $i) and print it but it print nothig. Does it depend on server? Is it possible to get no answer?

Comment: Without the `-q` parameter it will wait for user input. Try `out=$(echo -n "\c" | nc -w 10 $1 $i)`